# How to enable FATAL warnings in Modules which inherit from my base module without mentioning FATAL in all of them?

Tags: perl

I use the mojolicious framework to write  Web-App.
Mojo::Base has a nice feature to enable stricture and warnings in all modules which inherit from it.

However in a set of core modules for my App I want all warnings to be FATAL.
This is achieved by writing

`use warnings FATAL => qw( all );`

I want to write a module like Mojo::Base which just makes warnings fatal for every caller which inherits from it. This way I will avoid writing the above code all the time.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can make a module that imports warnings in its `import` sub:

```
package MyBase;
use warnings;

sub import {
    warnings->import(FATAL => qw( all ));
}

1;
```

Then FATAL warnings will be enabled in every module that `use` it:

```
use MyBase;
print "<<$a>>\n";
```

Yields:

```
Name "main::a" used only once: possible typo at warn_enable.pl line 2.
Use of uninitialized value $a in concatenation (.) or string at warn_enable.pl line 2.
```