# My Perl warnings are FATAL and I don't know why

Tags: apache, perl

I have two servers with the same configurations: httpd + mod_perl (I thought the settings were 100% the same), but in one server I got some perl warnings, while in the other server the same warnings get me FATAL errors. Look:

Server A log:
Use of uninitialized value in numeric eq (==) at

Server B log:
[Wed Jun 08 14:32:47 2016] **[error]** Use of uninitialized value in string eq at

In server A the request flow goes on and the user gets the desired result, but in server B the user gets a 500 error.

I am using

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

in the file on both servers.

Any  thoughts ?

Example of the code causing this warning/FATAL:

```
$allowed_sellers = any { $_ == $user->{user_id} } (111,123,222,345);
```

UPDATE:

I found this code in a module that I am using (Moo):

```
package Moo::_strictures;
use strict;
use warnings;

sub import {
  if ($ENV{MOO_FATAL_WARNINGS}) {
    require strictures;
    strictures->VERSION(2);
    @_ = ('strictures');
    goto &strictures::import;
  }
  else {
    strict->import;
    warnings->import;
  }
}

1;
```

But the env variable MOO_FATAL_WARNINGS seems to not be defined. Any thougts ?

SOLVED:

Guys, thanks a lot! We have finally discovered the problem: In server A the version of module Moo was 1.003 while server B was using a newer version 2.000001

Comment: Your assertion that they are the same error doesn't ring true.  Server A is complaining about some code with a `==` in it, while Server B is complaining about some code with a `eq` in it.  Without more *relevant* info, I'm not sure we can help.

Comment: If you are correct about all warnings being fatal, you can remedy it with `use warnings NONFATAL => 'all'` at the start of your code. I offer that as a diagnostic technique rather than a solution

Comment: @tjd: While the instances of the error may be different, they are both warnings in the category `uninitialized`, and the program is behaving as if `use warnings FATAL => 'uninitialized'` is in place on server B and not on server A

Comment: Guys, thanks for the tips. I tried to use ```use warnings NONFATAL => 'all'```  but didn't work... maybe, in some dark place there is a file overriding this only in one server...

Comment: `use warnings;` is lexically scoped, and never crosses file boundaries, so the file name that usually follows the `Use of uninitialized value in string eq at ` you posted will have the `use warnings FATAL => 'all';` in it.

Comment: Or is loading some other module that is causing the same effect

Comment: Not according to [warnings](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html), and I can't reproduce it either by having it in a module I `use`.

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include the code around where the error occurs?

Comment: Guys, I put ```use warnings NONFATAL => 'all'``` at the top of the file in which the error occurs, but it didn't solve!!!! After this, I put the ```use warnings NONFATAL => 'all'``` right before the error, and this time, it worked... So, I guess, like @ysth told, there is some module, in a different version, that is messing this.

Comment: Is it possible to set this behavior (FATAL => 'ALL') in the mod_perl configuration ? Or in the environment ? It does not seems to be related to the code

Comment: @ysth: I was wrong in my statements above... I had my thinking hat off for the day. I'm sure what you meant is that the warning could have been spewed from within a use()d module. In this case, if the file in the warning is a calling script, still should be trivial to see what sub from what module is being called at that time.

Comment: @RafaelManoel it's almost certainly something you are loading in that file that is causing this.  See for example http://stackoverflow.com/q/4907954/17389 where someone wanted to set fatal warnings on all files that use a certain module.

Comment: Good point @ysth. I have updated the Question with a code found in the Moo module that I am using.

Comment: @RafaelManoel Good find. I wonder if something else is enabling strictures. Run your script in the debugger: `perl -d /path/to/script`. Enter `b strictures::import`, then `R`, then `T`; this will print a stack trace showing what (if anything) called `use strictures;`

Comment: Also, which version of Moo are you using? Until v2.000000, `use Moo;` enabled strictures by default, which meant fatal warnings. You can check the version by running `perl -MMoo -le'print $Moo::VERSION'`

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot I think you mean before version 2

Comment: @ysth I just copied that out of the change log. 2, 2.000000, 4/2, what's the difference? ;P

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot I mean "until" sounds like until and including

Comment: Guys, I think we found it! In the server B (where the error occurs) I'm using Moo version 1.003, while in the server A the version is 2.000001. Next step: update the Moo version in the Server B. \o/

Comment: @ysth Oh, I see. Good point.

Comment: @RafaelManoel Great! I posted an answer in case someone in the future has the same issue. Can you please move your comments about the Moo versions you're using into your question? That will make it easier to follow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Before version 2](https://metacpan.org/changes/distribution/Moo), calling `use Moo;` enabled [strictures](https://metacpan.org/pod/strictures), which makes all warnings fatal except for a few categories. This caused a lot of problems*, so warnings are no longer fatal in version 2 and up.

To fix, upgrade Moo to the latest version. While you're at it, you should really fix the cause of the warnings, too.

---

* See the following discussions:

- [Default fatalization of warnings needs mst's clarification before new major strictures](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=93004)
- [fatal warnings are a ticking time bomb](http://blogs.perl.org/users/peter_rabbitson/2014/01/fatal-warnings-are-a-ticking-time-bomb-via-chromatic.html)
- [Moo 2 and strictures 2](http://shadow.cat/blog/matt-s-trout/moo-2-strictures-2/)